# common lisp: write to file complains of type

Tags: common-lisp

This lisp code should take a file of regular numbers and their roman equivalents `1=I` etc. and create one big alist of dotted pairs `(1 . I)` out of them, then write that alist to a file.

```
(defun arabic_to_roman (filename)
     (let ((arab_roman_dp '())
           (arab nil)
           (roman nil)
           (in (open filename :if-does-not-exist nil)))

       (when in
         (loop for line = (read-line in nil)
               while line do
               (setq arab (subseq line 0 (search "=" line)))
               (setq roman (subseq line (1+ (search "=" line)) (length line)))
               (setf arab_roman_dp (acons arab roman arab_roman_dp))
               (format t "~S ~S~%" arab roman)))
         (close in)

         (with-open-file (stream #p"ar_out.txt"
                                 :direction :output
                                 :if-exists :overwrite
                                 :if-does-not-exist :create )
           (format stream arab_roman_dp))
                                           ;(format t "~S"  arab_roman_dp)
         ))
```

produces this error in slime/sbcl:

```
in: DEFUN ARABIC_TO_ROMAN
;     (FORMAT STREAM ARAB_ROMAN_DP)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   Derived type of ARAB_ROMAN_DP is
;     (VALUES LIST &OPTIONAL),
;   conflicting with its asserted type
;     (OR (VECTOR CHARACTER) (VECTOR NIL) BASE-STRING FUNCTION).
;   See also:
;     The SBCL Manual, Node "Handling of Types"
```

The commented line (next to last) works fine -- before I put in the `(format stream arab_roman_dp)`

Here's a sample of the input file:

```
1=I
2=II
3=III
4=IV=IIII
5=V
6=VI
7=VII
8=VIII=IIX
9=IX=VIIII
10=X
11=XI
12=XII
13=XIII
```

...

```
4994=MMMMCMXCIV
4995=MMMMCMXCV
4996=MMMMCMXCVI
4997=MMMMCMXCVII
4998=MMMMCMXCVIII
4999=MMMMCMXCIX
```

Not sure what I've done wrong here. Basically, I want to write the big list of dotted pairs I create to a file.

```
((4999 . MMMMCMXCIX) (4998 . MMMMCMXCVIII) ... (1 . I))
```

Comment: This sounds more like a class exercise, but just in case you're actually trying to generate Roman numerals in Common Lisp, **format** already includes directives, ~@R and ~:@R that will do that.  E.g., `(format t "~@R" 4)` prints `IV`.

Comment: No, I'm just trying to work through a few textbooks on my own. No school. I'm two years away from retirement age, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to FORMAT must be a control string. The second argument you have in the code, `arab_roman_dp`, is a list. SBCL can detect this mistake and is correct to signal a warning for this code.

Comment: I've been trying various "~..." combinations, but I always get `The value NIL is not of type NUMBER.` What should this `format...` look like?

Comment: The format string looks fine, what you have to change is the output stream from T to stream: (format stream "~S"  arab_roman_dp)

Comment: `The value NIL is not of type NUMBER.` error comes up with `(format stream "~S" arab_roman_dp)`

Comment: Finally solved it: Yes, `(format stream "~S" arab_roman_dp)` did finally work ... after I removed the extra newline from the input file. Any way to guard against such a thing?